# apache no esta reconociendo el alias en mis webs

Tags: apache, servidor, apache2

Si me podrían ayudar con este esta consulta. Estoy trabajando en un servidor ubuntu con apache2 tengo dos webs laravel que las uso para mi backend.
El problema que tengo es que no reconoce el alias de la segunda web y me da el error 404
NOT FOUND al intentar entrar en la web.
Al entrar con la url ip que uso http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx sin problema entra en /var/www/html pero al usar el http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/meditime/ es ahi donde me sale este problema 404
NOT FOUND
mi con figuracion de apache es la siguiente.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName xxx.xx.xx.xxx

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/html_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/html_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

y este meditime.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
            Alias /meditime /var/www/meditime

    DocumentRoot /var/www/meditime
    <Directory /var/www/meditime>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/meditime_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/meditime_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

las rutas estan bien ya se probaron las dos webs y se abren sin problema. El problema es que no esta asumiendo el alias.
Ademas ya estan todas habilitadas.

Desda ya gracias!!